# Select2 dropdown not communicating with source

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement Select2 in my script. But when I run my script I still get a normal dropdown. Does someone know what is wrong?

I have put the javascript part in the `<head>` of my website:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Setting default configuration here or you can set through configuration object as seen below
$.fn.select2.defaults = $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults, {
    allowClear: true, // Adds X image to clear select
    closeOnSelect: true, // Only applies to multiple selects. Closes the select upon selection.
    placeholder: 'Select...',
    minimumResultsForSearch: 15 // Removes search when there are 15 or fewer options
});

$(document).ready(

function () {

    // Single select example if using params obj or configuration seen above
    var configParamsObj = {
        placeholder: 'Select an option...', // Place holder text to place in the select
        minimumResultsForSearch: 3 // Overrides default of 15 set above
    };
    $("#singleSelectExample").select2(configParamsObj);
});
</script>
</head>
```

In the `<body>` I have the dropdown:

```
<select id="singleSelectExample">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

When I run the script I still get a normal dropdown instead of the dropdown with search. Does someone know what is wrong?

Comment: Um, have you loaded jQuery libs ?

Comment: I also loaded the jQuery lib `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: See edit in first post

Comment: Include your select2 scripts correctly. You are missing closing > in css and js

Comment: @CodeThing I updated my first post. It looks like jQuery is not loaded. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code that you provided you have a couple of errors

1. You load the css in a script tag (you should load in link tag)
   from `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css"</script>`
   change to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />`
2. You do not properly close the script tag in select2.js
   see: 
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"</script>`

Also do not load css and js from github . I have noticed sometimes that github does not send the proper header about the content type of the scripts (e.x. application/javascript) 
Better load from a cdn like cdnjs

I have made these changes and select2 renders correctly
so my new tags that you load in the head were the following

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The script is still not working with the changes. See: http://jsfiddle.net/dw1265Lh/2/. The jquery is not loaded.

Comment: Please check in codepen `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMpPLb` , it loads and renders correct. Also the way you have loaded the scripts in jsfiddle was wrong. You need to load them on the left via the resources options. Check also in jsfiddle, i ve included the scripts in resources=>http://jsfiddle.net/dw1265Lh/9/

Comment: It worked. Thanks. The problem was that I had an old reference in my script